# I am trying to implement barcode reader using camera. The camera screen pops up but, not decoding the barcode

Tags: vue.js, barcode, barcode-scanner, vuejs3

[I am trying to implement a barcode reader using Vue js. the camera for scanning barcode popping up as expected but it cannot **decode** the barcode.]

[here I want to console the decoded value with the variable result using the *onDecode()* method since the function is not executing ]

> installed **vue-barcode-reader --save**  via npm install

```
<template>

<StreamBarcodeReader @decode="onDecode"/>
</template>

<script >
import { StreamBarcodeReader } from "vue-barcode-reader";

export default ({
    components : { StreamBarcodeReader },

    data(){ },

    methods: {
        onDecode(result) {
             console.log(result);
        },
    }
})
</script>
```